# How to create specific django-model field, contains a date and unique number per day?

Tags: django

I create a internet-shop on django and have the following problem.

How to create a django model-field for order`s number, contains a date and unique number per day?

This option is described in the assignment and others will not suit me.

**UPD:**
order number should look like this: yyyymmdd + unique order`s num per day. The next day, this num will start from the beginning.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Do you want the field to have a complete date(yyyy/mm/dd) or just the day's number?

Comment: order number should look like this: yyyymmdd + unique order`s num per day. The next day, this num will start from the beginning.

Comment: @bekaryukovmv I would use a string field using `CharField` with a unique constraint and generate the order number with a function.

Answer (score 0):

As a result, I made like this. Maybe someone will come in handy.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import datetime

def get_num(date=datetime.now()):
    date = date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    if Order.objects.all().last():
        last_order = Order.objects.all().last()
        if last_order.number[0:8] == date:
            num = int(last_order.number[8::]) + 1
        else:
            num = 1
    else:
        return f'{date}1'
    return(f'{date}{num}')

class Order(models.Model):

    number = models.CharField(max_length=12, default=get_num, verbose_name='номер заказа')
    ...
```